# JavaScript TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined - discord bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord.io

I must start this question by saying that I have very little knowledge of javascript (I'm practiced in Java) and just wanted to make a (somewhat) simple Discord bot that would say messages at random times. I Frankensteined 2 pieces of code from various tutorials together and currently have this:

```
var Discord = require('discord.io');
var logger = require('winston');
var auth = require('./auth.json');
//random bot code
var randomMessage;
var randOn = false;
var responseArray = [ //add more messages here
  "Ayy, lmao!",
  "Say what?",
  "roflmaotntpmp"
];

var prefix = "!";
var timer = [5,10]; //set min and max in seconds for random messages


// Configure logger settings
logger.remove(logger.transports.Console);
logger.add(new logger.transports.Console, {
    colorize: true
});
logger.level = 'debug';
// Initialize Discord Bot
var bot = new Discord.Client({
   token: auth.token,
   autorun: true
});
bot.on('ready', function (evt) {
    logger.info('Connected');
    logger.info('Logged in as: ');
    logger.info(bot.username + ' - (' + bot.id + ')');
});


bot.on('message', (msg) => {

  if (msg.content.startsWith(prefix + "on")) {
        if (randOn) {
            msg.channel.sendMessage("Already running.");
        }
        else {
            msg.channel.sendMessage("Random message started.")
        randomMessage = setTimeout(function() {
                randMsg(msg.channel);
            }, 1000*timer[0]);
        }
  }
  else if (msg.content.startsWith(prefix + "off")) {
        if (randOn) {
            clearTimeout(randomMessage);
            msg.channel.sendMessage("Random message disabled.");
        }
        else {
            msg.channel.sendMessage("Not running.");
        }
  }


});



function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
}

function randMsg(msgChan) {
    console.log("callback");
    var interval = 1000*randomIntFromInterval(timer[0],timer[1]);
  var rand = randomIntFromInterval(0,responseArray.length-1);
  if(responseArray[rand]) {
    msgChan.sendMessage(responseArray[rand]);
  }
    randomMessage = setTimeout(function() {
        randMsg(msgChan);
    }, interval);
}
```

The problem is occurring in this block:

```
 bot.on('message', (msg) => {

      if (msg.content.startsWith(prefix + "on")) {
            if (randOn) {
                msg.channel.sendMessage("Already running.");
            }
```

Every time I attempt to command the bot in my discord chat (!on) I get the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined" in Node.js/command prompt. I've tried various things to fix it (removing "content" from both msg.content... statements - no complaints but absolutely nothing happens) but... I honestly have no idea what I'm doing. I've checked every post on the internet that deals with similar things and nothing has been able to answer this. I'm hoping it's a simple syntax thing/something not declared properly... If you have some time and pity for me, please help. I know I've gotten myself into a mess but I refuse to abandon it!

Let me know what other information I can provide to help.

Comment: what is the value of `msg` when the handler is called? can you `console.log(msg)` it and share the output?

Comment: not sure if I did this right, but I placed "console.log(msg);" right before the start of the if statement containing msg.content...etc. when I ran the bot (node bot.js) and tried to use a command in discord, it just printed my discord name in command prompt right before it threw the error @shkaper

Comment: Put in a console.dir(msg) this will give you an exploded dump of the object, including all members and methods. Insert this after the line: bot.on('message', (msg) => {

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is, that you mix `discord.js` with `discord.io`

`discord.js` is object oriented where `discord.io` is not, so in `discord.io` your message is already a string!

Example discord.io message event.

```
bot.on('message', function(user, userID, channelID, message, event) {
    if (message === "ping") {
        bot.sendMessage({
            to: channelID,
            message: "pong"
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe jam something like `if(!msg || !msg.content) return;` in there to bail out if the `msg` object or its `content` property is undefined.

```js
bot.on('message', (msg) => {

  if(!msg || !msg.content) return;

  if (msg.content.startsWith(prefix + "on")) {
        if (randOn) {
            msg.channel.sendMessage("Already running.");
        }
        else {
            msg.channel.sendMessage("Random message started.")
        randomMessage = setTimeout(function() {
                randMsg(msg.channel);
            }, 1000*timer[0]);
        }
  }
  else if (msg.content.startsWith(prefix + "off")) {
        if (randOn) {
            clearTimeout(randomMessage);
            msg.channel.sendMessage("Random message disabled.");
        }
        else {
            msg.channel.sendMessage("Not running.");
        }
  }


});
```

Comment: so I did that, and it stopped at the "if(!msg || !msg.content) return;" line. i then isolated each of those to see which was the problem ("if(!msg) return", then i did msg.content) and my findings were that it seems msg.content is the issue, because it only stopped at "if(!msg.content) return". in theory, the content should be the input of the discord user, I think. where to go from here.....@Will

Comment: ok, so I printed msg.content, and it indeed came up as "undefined".

Comment: I was trying to look at the documentation for `Discord.Client` and it looks like your code follows their example. I'm not sure why the object you are getting when that event fires is missing the `content` property but maybe if it's missing, you can just ignore the event.